# Array.sort() is not working correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net

Suppose an array consists of values:

```
dim arrnum() as integer=nothing
```

`arrnum` consists of values (3,8,6,15,2,10)

```
while using Array.sort(arrnum)
```

valuse are sorted like way. (10,15,2,3,6,5)

Actually I need values in a sorted way.

Can you help me out?

Comment: You sort string array. If you need integer array make it as integer. Show your code.

Comment: Looks like you actually have a string array, not an integer array; however: `while using Array.sort(arrnum)` - what does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sorted array is actually `10, 15, 2, 3, 6, 8` (ie, containing the same elements as the original), it looks like it's sorting lexicographically (a fancy way of saying string sorting rather than numeric sorting).

In other words, `10` and `15` are less than `2` if you're sorting based on character data, since `1` is less than `2`.

That makes me doubt the veracity of your statement that they're actually integers, so that would be the first thing I'd be checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some mistake to define array
Take look below code this worked

```
Dim arrnum() As Integer = Nothing
arrnum = {3, 8, 6, 15, 2, 10}
Array.Sort(arrnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsuprisingly, the code

```
Sub Main
    Dim array = {3, 8, 6, 15, 2, 10}
    System.Array.Sort(array)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", array))
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

works entirely as I would expect.

**You are doing something(s) wrong.**

**Before we can help you out you need to show us exactly what you are doing.**

I'm drawn to suggest you are sorting an array of `String` but the `6` and `5` in your results are reversed for alphabetical order. Note that the value `5` is not even present in the initial array. Additionaly, `Array.Sort` does not return anything so there would be `nothing` to pass to a `using` or `while`.